# Post request with strange behavior

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a node / express server set up, which is communicating with a mysql database (both of which are hosted on AWS, in elastic beanstalk environment and RDS instance respectively). I have created a simple create account authentication project in react, which I am currently running locally. I communicate to the server with a post request.

```
createAccount = (event) => {
  console.log("hello from createAccount");
  const isValid = this.validate();
  if (!isValid) {
    console.log("not valid");
    return false;
  } else {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("firstName", this.state.firstName);
    formData.append("lastName", this.state.lastName);
    formData.append("username", this.state.username);
    formData.append("passcode", this.state.passcode);
    console.log(formData);

    fetch("https://www.myurl.com/createUser", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers({
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      }),
      body: formData,
    });
  }
};
```

And here is the server side code:

```
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "my-endpoint",
  user: "****",
  password: "****",
  port: "****",
  database: "****",
});

app.post("/createUser", function (request, response) {
  console.log("/createUser");
  console.log(request.body);
  const createUser = `CALL CreateUser('${request.body.firstName}', '${request.body.lastName}', '${request.body.username}', '${request.body.passcode}')`;
  mysqlConnection.query(createUser, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("SUCCESSFULLY CREATED A USER ACCOUNT");
      response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      mysqlConnection.end();
    }
  });
});
```

However, my post request is doing something strange...about 2/3 of the time, all goes as expected. The user creates an account and the information is successfully added to my database. However, the rest of the time everything seems to run fine (through examination of my console.log check points), but the information is not added to my database...the user does not successfully create an account. When this happens, I open up the logs from AWS to examine what the server is doing, and nothing is printed that I would expect. My new account information is not printed (while is usually is), and there is not an error printed either. This is a head scratcher. Is there some reason my post requests would not reach my server, BUT only part of the time? I am at a loss...

I ran the application totally in my local environment (changed my request to my local server as opposed to the one hosted on elastic beanstalk). This worked 100% of the time (please note that this is the same exact server code). I am perplexed as to this behavior, which is apparently something to do with the hosted version on elastic beanstalk in AWS. What is causing this behavior, and how can I fix it?

I switched back to the hosted server for further testing. I was just spam creating accounts to see if I could notice any patterns. The application creates a successful account about 1 in every 5 times. The other four times it will not save any info to the database. It is not a problem with my field data (I have implemented a little error checking), because I just spam the same info over and over until it finally creates. It eventually does, but only after about 4 tries.

Below is my post request with the added connection.end(), as well as where I initially connection to my database as requested in the comments.

```
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "my-endpoint",
  user: "****",
  password: "****",
  port: "****",
  database: "****",
});

app.post("/createUser", function (request, response) {
  console.log("/createUser");
  console.log(request.body);
  const createUser = `CALL CreateUser('${request.body.firstName}', '${request.body.lastName}', '${request.body.username}', '${request.body.passcode}')`;
  mysqlConnection.query(createUser, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("SUCCESSFULLY CREATED A USER ACCOUNT");
      response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      mysqlConnection.end();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetch` Function returns a promise. Therefore you need to add a `.then` block. If you don't use `.then` The code following will not be waiting for the fetch to be completed. Please check and let me know.

What's a promise? A promise is resolved eventually and return a value unlike a synchronous function where the value is returned immediately.

```
fetch('https://www.myurl.com/createUser', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }),
    body: formData
}).then(() => {
    Console.log(‘done’)

})
```

The second issue I see is that your server side express endpoint `/createUser` Should only be completed once the mysql query is completed. Therefore you should call `res.end` To end the request after the query is completed. So that the frontend will get the response from the api after the queries are completed.

```
mysqlConnection.query(createUser, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send(new Error('error result'));

    } else {
        console.log('created user');
        res.send('success result')
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried both of those things. Unfortunately, something is still not working correctly. Upon examination of the logs from AWS, it appears that my post request is not even reaching my server route (during the instances when it doesn't work). The strangest thing is that I have another post request for editing account information. This one works ALL the time. I compared the code for each, and I have no differences. I can't figure out why one works but the other does not.

Comment: I don't know if it is important that the info from the .then or the res.end are not printing their respective information.

Comment: Also i want you to try adding the `connection.end()` part as i showed in my edit. Please observe the network tab of the browser's developer tools and see the status of each request and their outputs. Could you also include the server side code where you create the mysql connection.

Comment: I added the post request with connection.end, as well as my initial connection with the database to the above post. I am currently in a state of no functionality. When I print off the logs from AWS, it doesn't even appear that the server is making a successful connection to the database. connection.end() seems to have messed something up. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: yes it definitely caused trouble. because your connection is created when the express server starts and we are closing it in the query. so the connection is not available for the subsequent queries. remove it for now. did you check the browser's developer tools and observe the requests for the successful and failure scenarios.

Comment: Yes I did. It is being so weird. The post requests has a status 200. However, I am still getting absolutely no response from the /createUser route. It all runs fine on my local environment. But when I test again on AWS, I get zero response. No error or successful behavior.

Comment: what does the response contain in the developer tools when it success. Nothing ?

Comment: i just want to try res.send and res.error as i showed in my edit. Could you try it as well ?

Comment: after you add that code, please observe what is received as response in the developer tools

Comment: Ok I just stumbled onto something. In my react app, in the headers for the fetch request I have my traffic to the access-control-allow-origin set to * (all). I switched this to the specific url of my server and it now seems to be functioning. Do you know anything about this? I'm confused why the * would not suffice...although it now works as expected, this is still confusing behavior. Like I said, I had another post request, which is also set to * and it works fine.

Comment: you don't need to send access-control-allow-origin from the frontend as one of the parameters, try removing it. Because the browser will do a preflight http options request to see whether the origin is allowed in the list of allowed origins. check and let me know.